# Диапазон символов в регулярном выражении

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Какие символы включает регулярное выражение `[а-яА-Я]+`? Известно, что оно не включает символы `ё` и `ъ`. И для того, чтобы охватить весь алфавит русского языка нужно писать `[а-яА-ЯёЁъЪ]+` ? Или есть какие-то ещё символы алфавита русского языка, которое это выражение не включает? Как узнать весь диапазон включённых в регулярное выражение символов?

Comment: [`[а-яА-Я]`](https://regex101.com/r/uylDLk/1) из *русских* букв не включает только `ё` и `Ё`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Регулярные выражения Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) поддерживают стандарт регулярных выражений для Юникода ([Unicode® Technical Standard #18 UNICODE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/)). Соответственно, диапазоны символов считаются по кодовым позициям в Юникоде.

Буквы русского алфавита занимают в Юникоде [позиции с 0410 по 044F](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5), кроме букв «ё» и «Ё», которые по историческим причинам поставлены на позиции не соответствующие русскому алфавиту ([найдите их в таблице символов](https://unicode-table.com/en/)). Это и вызывает необходимость указывать их отдельно.

> Есть какие-то ещё символы алфавита русского языка, которое это выражение не включает

Нет, даже для твердого знака не нужно делать исключения.

> Как узнать весь диапазон включённых в регулярное выражение символов?

По кодовым позициям. В Java числовое значение символа (char) соответствует его позиции в Юникоде. Соответственно, можно задать переменные char для границ диапазона и пройтись циклом по всем символам. Например, следующий код выводит все символы, входящие в диапазон от «А» до «Я» и их позиции в Юникоде.

```
for(char ch = 'А'; ch<='Я'; ch++) {
    System.out.println(ch +" ("+ ((int) ch)+")");
}
```